# No module named streamlit.__main__; ‘streamlit’ is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: streamlit

When I try to deploy streamlit to heroku I get this below error. How can I fix it?

No module named streamlit.main; ‘streamlit’ is a package and cannot be directly executed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried and this works for me:

```
python -m streamlit.cli run path/to/your/app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you too.. `python -m streamlit.cli iris_eda_app.py`

Answer (score 0):

The `streamlit` command lives in your virtualenv's `bin/` folder. It looks like `pipenv run` isn't looking in that folder, and is instead finding the *package* called streamlit, and trying to execute that instead.

Without seeing any details of what your Heroku deployment looks like, it's hard to offer concrete advice to fix this issue. But from your screenshots, it looks like you're executing this command from within a pipenv shell. Since you're already in the shell, you don't need to use `pipenv run streamlit run ...` to run the `streamlit` command; having the shell activated means that the `streamlit` command will already be on your $PATH.

When you have the shell active, doing this should work instead:

```
streamlit run iris_eda_app.py
```

Alternately, you could forego `pipenv` and manage your virtualenv directly. I've put together a minimal working example of a Streamlit app that's deployable to Heroku. It uses a plain `requirements.txt` file instead of a `Pipfile`: https://github.com/tconkling/streamlit_heroku_example